# compile-time check with const char* (nullptr)

Tags: c++, compile-time, nullptr

I have a template class that takes a string literal as parameter. The code works fine - but I've got one question, whether it is possible to use compile-time check to skip the generating of `if (S)` or `else` block body at all? (Something like the __if_exists or #if, traits, etc). I understand that I could have a specialized `A<nullptr>` that defines a different `print()` function, but also want to know whether there's other (more simple) ways of doing this. Thanks!

```
template<char const* S = nullptr>
class A
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        if (S)
            cout << S << endl;
        else
            cout << "nullptr" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yay. The simplest way is to turn on compiler optimizations.

Comment: Good answer, thanks :) I don't fully control the compiler options. In fact our compiler rejects even the code above (`if (nullptr)`) as "conditional expression is constant".

Comment: @userXXX Which compiler do you use, actually?

Comment: I use VC++ - but the one runs on our code server is something that I don't control. (I should have picked up a user name.. :))

Comment: Indeed :) I understand. I'm not great at C++ and I don't knos if this should compile, but that's an interesting issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, can't you set the default value of S as "nullptr" or any other constant string? Of course, this works when you don't actually need S to be NULL, but it will skip the if check.

Comment: Yes the default value of S is nullptr. I'm not sure I'm following you, can you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

add a function,

```
constexpr const char* getStr(){
   return S? S : "null";
}
```

then it becomes,

```
void print(){
   std::cout << getStr() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the print/cout is just for demonstration, the actual code is more complex that this, adding a new function would still result in the same `if .. else ..` code block.